# Fill datagrid column each with a different query

Tags: c#

I have the following tables

```
category {name}
purchase {pdtname, amount, catName}
sales {pdtname, amount, catName}
```

I want to add a datagrid and display the names of categories from category table
I already did this using this code

```
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name from cate", ConnectionInfo.con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "الفئة";
```

It's working fine and the categories are displayed.

But I also want to display beside each category name the total expenses and total sales respectively

I tried writing this code but I know its incomplete or wrong

```
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                double exp2 = 0, rev2 = 0;
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select amount from purchase where year=@year and month=@month and cat=@cat ", ConnectionInfo.con);

                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", comboBox2.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", comboBox3.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    exp2 += Convert.ToDouble(dr2[0]);
                    MessageBox.Show(exp2 + "");
                }
                dr2.Close();

            }
            dr3.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            ConnectionInfo.con.Close();
        }
```

How can I get the numbers to be printed in the datagrid column 
so for each category I can view the total expenses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, (SELECT SUM(amount) from purchase where year=@year and month=@month and catName=c.Name) from cate c
```